# Remove multiples values from an array PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I' ve this example:

```
SELECT array_remove(Array[1,2,3,4,5,6], 1);
```

Let's suppose that I want to remove 1 and 2 at once, how can I do it? How can I remove N elements?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in operator.  But you can easily `unnest()` and recreate the array:

```
select (select array_agg(el order by n)
        from (values (Array[1,2,3,4,5,6])) v(ar)
             unnest(ar) with ordinality u(el, n)
        where el not in (1, 2)
       )
```

If you have a second array:

```
where not el = any(:input_array)
```